# Is there a word to differentiate a measure in each hand?

Tags: sheet-music, terminology

Say I have a piano partition, with 1 measure/bar. How can I call the right hand staff measure and the left hand staff measure ? Is there a word to make the distinction between the two hands measure together and each one individually ?

I'm not being pedantic here :p I need to know for a personal project and I'd prefer having the right term than just "right hand measure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper stave/Lower stave.  Treble stave/Bass stave.

Comment: Yes, indeed you may call them upper stave and lower stave. Treble stave and bass stave will often do, but won't do where the two staves use the same clef.